# Need to associate one field with another in event, using bash script

Tags: shell-script, json, jq

I've gotten most of what I need done, but am stuck at the last part.
I need to download the campaign from *this month*, but the url is associated w/ a campaign id and not the month (makes sense). I need to be able to associate this month with the campaign id(s) of this month.

My script is thus:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Retrieve phishline token
var=$(curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{
"bof_ticket_user": "nope",
"bof_ticket_pw": "nopenopenope",
"api_key": "nope-nope-nope-nope-nope"}' 
"https://api.phishline.com/nope/rest/authenticate" | jq -r ."data"."access_token")

#define latest campaign
var2=$(curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $var" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" "https://api.phishline.com/nope/rest/campaigns" | jq -r ."data"[-1]."cutoffDate")
#Clean up cutoffDate variable to %Y-%m format
var3=$(echo $var2 | cut -c1-7)
# Assign current date in %Y-%m format
datedit=$("date +%Y-%m")

if datedit == $var3
#download latest campaign
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $var" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" "https://api.phishline.com/nope/rest/campaignresults/$whichvar"
```

Can anyone make any suggestions to make this better?
Edit: Hopefully this will clarify what I need to get done:
The script needs to download the current months campaign data. The current months campaign data is found by associating the "cutoffDate" in the campaign list to identify the campaign for this month, with the id field in that campaign. Both fields are shown in the rest/campaigns results

Comment: Apart from the syntax errors that could be found by posting your code into https://shellcheck.net/, what's the question?

Comment: The script needs to download the current months campaign data. The current months campaign data is found by associating the "cutoffDate" in the campaign list to identify the campaign for this month, with the id field in that campaign. Both fields are shown in the rest/campaigns results.

Comment: Please [put that in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/494496/edit), where it can be seen easily by anyone considering answering.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear about what maps to what, but if your bash version is >= 4, you can use an associative array:

```
declare -A mapping=(
    [2019-01]="some-id"
    [2019-02]="some-other-id"
)

mon=$(process that retrieves the YYYY-MM)
campaign_id=${mapping[$mon]}
if [[ -z $campaign_id ]]; then
    echo "no mapping for month $mon"
else
    go fetch with "$campaign_id"
fi
```